# A table of images, under a div

Tags: javascript, css

There's a nice javascript library for displaying photos on iPhone called "jaipho".  I'm trying to adapt its slider implementation to work in a normal browser, and I'm having some problems.

Here's the summary of how its slider works:  there's a table of images arranged horizontally.  The table is contained in a div which has overflow:hidden, and then some javascript moves the table by setting its marginLeft to some negative number.

More specifically:  the table is placed inside the div by setting its innerHTML in javascript.  Each table cell is of class "slide", which is set by CSS to be the width of the iPhone.  The photos are dynamically placed in the table cells by calls to appendChild, so that they need not all be loaded at once.

It works great on the iPhone in MobileSafari.  With the photos arranged horizontally, one can slide out of view to the left while the next one slides in from the right.

Now I try to get it to work on a Mac in a browser window.  The problem is getting a constant width for each cell -- I can't use CSS because the width I want is window.innerWidth, not a fixed width like the iPhone.  I've tried setting the table cells with "width" tags (or "style" tags) to the width of the window.  Looking at what Chrome thinks is going on in its Javascript Console, it's as if the table is ignoring the effort of the cells to set their width, and rather the table is setting their widths to be very narrow in an effort to entirely fit inside the window.  (Or into its containing div, even though it's set to "overflow: hidden".)

Anyone have any suggestions how to coerce a table into being very, very wide in pixels, even though only some small part of it will ever be shown at a time?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Can you show your code so far/what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I recently built something like this, and here is the structure:

```
<div id="outer_container" style="width: 500px; height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="slider" style="width: 5000px;">
        <div id="slide1" style="float: left; width: 500px;">...</div>
        <div id="slide2" style="float: left; width: 500px;">...</div>
        <div id="slide3" style="float: left; width: 500px;">...</div>
        <!-- add as many as you want, just make sure it fits in the 5000px width above -->
        <div style="clear: both;"><div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the slider works by adjusting the css `left` property of the the 'slider' div. So basically the viewing window is 500px as well the width of each 'slide'. I guess the key is the `float: left` on each slide.

To see this div structure in action, check out the top section in the right column that I coded on [this site](http://www.smartcarpet.com)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the cells to take the proper width, you have to adjust the table width to accommodate all those cells. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/USRww/1/. I'm resizing the table to accommodate all cells, assuming that each cell will be 100% of the browser window's width. I'm using percentages there, so everything is fluid.

That markup is using a table as you suggested, but I'd advise just using a container div there with a bunch of floated divs for each cell.